# Error with JQuery DataTables oCol is undefined dialog

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery DataTables to populate data in two separate tables in the same page. However, I am getting the following error:

> oCol is undefined

..in a dialog box. Please help me solve this.This is my code:

```
<table class="assignment">
<tr>
<th>Available Product License Types</th>
<th></th>
<th>Assigned Product License Types</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="leftcontent">
Select: <a href="#" onclick="return ASLM.Datatables.selectAll   ($('#availableProductLicenseTypeTable'));">all</a>,                            <a href="#" onclick="return ASLM.Datatables.selectNone($('#availableProductLicenseTypeTable'));">none</a>            <table id="availableProductLicenseTypeTable" class="display small noshadow">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>View Only</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <c:forEach var="availableProductLicenseType" items="${availableProductLicenseType}">
 <tr>
 <td>
 ${availableProductLicenseType.id}
 </td>
 <td>
                            ${availableProductLicenseType.productFamilyName}${' '}${availableProductLicenseType.productName}
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${availableProductLicenseType.needsExplicitAssignment}">*${availableProductLicenseType.licenseTypeName}
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>${availableProductLicenseType.licenseTypeName}
                                 </c:otherwise>
                           </c:choose>
                        </td>
                        <td>${availableProductLicenseType.isViewOnly}
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>   

        <td class="buttons">
        <input type="button" value="&gt;" onclick="moveProductLicenseTypesAvailableToAssigned()"/></br>
        <input type="button" value="&lt;" onclick="moveProductLicenseTypesAssignedToAvailable()"/></br>
    </td>
    <td class="rightcontent">
        Select: <a href="#" onclick="return ASLM.Datatables.selectAll($('#assignedProductLicenseTypeTable'));">all</a>, 
                <a href="#" onclick="return ASLM.Datatables.selectNone($('#assignedProductLicenseTypeTable'));">none</a>
        <table id="assignedProductLicenseTypeTable" class="display small noshadow">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>View Only</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <c:forEach var="assignedProductLicenseType" items="${assignedProductLicenseType}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ${assignedProductLicenseType.id}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${assignedProductLicenseType.productFamilyName}${' '}${assignedProductLicenseType.productName}
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${assignedProductLicenseType.needsExplicitAssignment}">*${assignedProductLicenseType.licenseTypeName}
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>${assignedProductLicenseType.licenseTypeName}
                                 </c:otherwise>
                           </c:choose>                                                           

                           <input type="checkbox" name="isViewOnly" id="isViewOnlyId"  value="${assignedProductLicenseType.isViewOnly}"  />
                          </td>
                          <td>${assignedProductLicenseType.isViewOnly}
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Edit your question with proper code formatting.

Comment: Add the tag <tbody> after </thead>

Comment: I have added <tbody> tag but still it is giving the same error.

Comment: Add </tbody> at the end also. Before </table>

Answer (score 0):

DataTables wants this format:

```
    <table>
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <td>Col 1 head</td>
       <td>Col 2 head</td>
       <td>Col 3 head</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Col 1 body</td>
      <td>Col 2 body</td>
      <td>Col 3 body</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't say so... Edit the code! You have a table inside another table a neigther of them are in that format!

Comment: In the above code if i ty to comment <th>View Only</th> and its corresponding data column , the pop up doesn't come , but since i need this column i have added it and on adding this it gives error. Could there be any other reason?

Comment: Hi i have changed the code as per the above table structure, but when im adding an additional column header as well as a data column, its giving the same error. Please help me out if im missing something.